# Nested Menus Using Jquery and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a nested navigation menu using jquery and css.

Currently my nav is hosted on xetecx.comxa.com. The problem is that the nested submenus don't shift towards the right on the main menu like a proper nested menu as shown in this video.

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0sCu8aj8zu2UzBxQnVlQWdzcUU/edit?usp=sharing
```

If you click on menu on xetecx.comxa.com

Here is my html

```
<ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="Nav Link 1"><img src="img/main.png" /></a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 1">Retails</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 1">R</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 2">S</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 3">A</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 4">C</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 2">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 3">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 4">Contact Us</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 1">R</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 2">S</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 3">A</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 4">C</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="Nav Link 1"><img src="img/social.png" /></a>
                <ul class="social">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 1"><img src="img/facebook.png" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 2"><img src="img/twitter.png" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 3"><img src="img/linked.png" /></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

And My Jquery

```
(function($) {

            //cache nav
            var nav = $("#topNav");

            //add indicators and hovers to submenu parents
            nav.find("li").each(function() {
                if ($(this).find("ul").length > 0) {

                    $("<span>").appendTo($(this).children(":first"));

                    //show subnav on hover
                    $(this).mouseenter(function() {
                        var ullist = $(this).find("ul");
                        ullist.stop(true, true).slideDown();

                        ullist.addClass("ullist");
                    });

                    //hide submenus on exit
                    $(this).mouseleave(function() {
                        var ullist = $(this).find("ul");
                        ullist.stop(true, true).slideUp();
                        ullist.removeClass("ullist");
                    });
                }
            });
        })(jQuery);
```

And the CSS I tried to use to solve the problem

```
nav > ul > li > a > img {
width:60px;
height:60px;
}


.social li > a > img{
    width:40px;
height:40px;
}
```

But it is not working out for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the css for

nav ul ul ul

which should have left as some 100px;

so

```
.nav ul ul ul
{
left:100px;
}
```